# how to increase the margin below this form

Tags: forms, margin

I'm not able to add some blank space below this form. The bottom of it still sticks to the edge of the page.

```
form {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

May I know how I can fix this

Thanks!

Comment: What is your html? More specifically, do you have any elements after the form?

Comment: it's this:  

`<div id="emailme">
   <form action="MAILTO:sjobs@apple.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
   Your E-mail:<br>
   <input type="text" name="mail" style="width:300px"><br>
   Message:<br>
   <textarea id="textbox" name="textarea"></textarea><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
  </div>`

the element after the font is the footer, but it's an icon with a fixed position at the corner. P.S. I didn't use the exact ID/class name in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can't add `margin-top` and/or `margin-bottom` to an element with `display: inline` because it will simply have no effect (although `margin-left` and `margin-right` will have) :)

Do you really need to apply `display: inline` to a `form`?

Perhaps if you could supply some more details I could try to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The margin clears an area around an element (outside the border). The margin does not have a background color, and is completely transparent.

The top, right, bottom, and left margin can be changed independently using separate properties. A shorthand margin property can also be used, to change all margins at once
In CSS, it is possible to specify different margins for different sides of an element

```
EXAMPLE:
ClassName Or ID{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: thanks but isn't it the same with what I have? `margin-bottom: 50px;` and there still isn't any space below the element. :( Am I misunderstanding something